# Is that necessary to publish app in market to implement deep linking for android

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, tap, deep-linking

I want to implement deep linking in my app but my app is not published in market now.I can successful send message from my application. When I tap on message it doesn't open my app which is installed on my device. I also installed facebook default app on my device. If my application is installed, it should open my application on tap my post on fb wall from my device otherwise it should use the browser.

I followed this link :-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/#deeplink

But I don't get field of Android Market App to put market url in documentation. It's written that this field is generated automatically. So is that necessary to publish app in market to implement deep linking. what I am missing?

Comment: Hi were you able to run that sample because I always get redirected to the web page even when the app is installed on my phone

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not need to be published for deep linking to work. What deep linking will do is try to go to your app first, and if your app is not on the device, it will use the android market url to guide the user to install your app. If you're testing, just having the app on your device should be enough.

Comment: +1 for ur answer.i have AppLinkingHowTo downloaded from github project and deeplinking is working in this project but this application opens a dialog.I want to open default facebook app for share and deep link is not working.my request   res = facebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");

Comment: What do you mean by you want to open the facebook app for share? A facebook.request method makes a Graph API request, and you must have the necessary permissions in order to post on behalf of the user. If you want to open the native facebook app instead, there's no officially supported mechanism for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

its not necessary to publish app. you can check it by installing app on your device. but if you are sending extra information with request. then there should be problem to receive that information against your requestId. because in my case i have receive information when app is intalled on my phone.. but i am unable to receive that requestId with information when app is not installed on my phone and notification takes me to play store to install app.  have to face such type of problem?